# Define a default return value to Haskell function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm learning Haskell and I'm doing the [H99](http://wiki.haskell.org/H-99:_Ninety-Nine_Haskell_Problems) (99 Haskell Problems). I'm working on the first set of problems and the topic is lists. The exercise I'm working on asks to return the last element of a list. And I did it in three different ways:

```hs
-- first approach using conditions
myLast :: [Integer] -> Integer
myLast l =
    if null l then
        -1
    else
        l !! ((length l) - 1)
```

```hs
-- second approach using guards
myLast :: [Integer] -> Integer
myLast l
    | null l = -1
    | otherwise = l !! ((length l) - 1)
```

```hs
-- third approach using last function
myLast :: [Integer] -> Integer
myLast l
    | null l = -1
    | otherwise = last l
```

Then I thought "Despite the fact that a list only accepts elements of a unique type, can I declare the list with two possible types?". Apparently I can:

```hs
myLast :: [Either Integer String] -> Either Integer String
```

But things get messy when I check if the list is empty. What should I return?

```hs
myLast :: [Either Integer String] -> Either Integer String
myLast l =
    if null l then
        -- what should I return?
    else
        l !! ((length l) - 1)
```

So my question is: is it possible to do define a default return value for this function in case the list is empty?

Maybe this is a silly question and must have skipped something on the documentation or on my internet searches, but it's been only a couple days that I'm learning Haskell and it's a completely different world to me (I only have experience with languages such as Python, Javascript, Java, C, Go...).

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

First of all: thanks for the answers! It helped me in many ways - not only by solving my problem but also making me understand a few concepts.

You folks gave me a small list of terms and concepts to google and I'm doing it since yesterday. So once again thanks!

Now about the problem. Reading the comments and reading more about lists I came up with this solution:

```hs
myLast :: [a] -> Maybe a
myLast xs = case xs of
    [] -> Nothing
    [x] -> Just x
    (_:xs) -> myLast xs
```

After a few hours reading the comments on this post, and searching about lists itself and patterns, things started to make sense. I'm glad.

Small progress is still progress, right?

Comment: Yes. Returning `-1` in a "error" case is utterly unidiomatic in Haskell.

Comment: @cafce25 didn't know it. Do you recommend any other resources to practice?

Comment: @leftaroundabout is there a type that will be valid to return in this situation?

Comment: Idiomatically such a function should return `Maybe Integer` or `Maybe (Either Integer String)` respectively with `Nothing` as the value when nothing was in the list, so there isn't a last.

Answer (score 5):

> can I declare the list with two possible types?

Yes, but that is not something `myLast` should be concerned about: you just make a function `myLast :: [a] -> Maybe a`. If `a ~ Either String Int`, that's fine. `myLast` does not need to know the type of the elements. With `myLast`, it can work with any type.

We return a `Nothing` in case the list is empty, and a `Just x` with `x` the last element if there is such element.

Using `length` and indexing are often *not* good ideas: that would mean that you enumerate *twice* over the same list, which can blow up memory, for example if the list is generated by a function. We can use recursion here. So something along the lines of:

```
myLast :: [a] -> Maybe a
myLast [] = …
myLast (x : xs) = go xs x
  where
    go [] x = …
    go (x : xs) _ = …
```

where I leave filling in the `…` parts as an exercise.

Using `-1` is likely not a good idea. Imagine a list `[0, -1]` and `[]`, both would then return `-1`, but the two scenarios are different.

Comment: Worth noting that "enumerate *twice* over the same list" sounds like it only does twice as much work as needed, but the problem can be significantly worse than that. Laziness often means that the list isn't in memory and can be generated one-item-at-a-time when it's first needed. Taking the last element of such a list can end up as a tight loop generating and discarding elements, but traversing it twice forces the whole thing into memory and then has to actually walk all the pointers, which can be **much** worse than a 2x slowdown. (WVO knows this, just unpacking the "can blow up memory" line)

Answer (score 3):

For that the standard library gives you `Maybe a`.

```
getLast :: [a] -> Maybe a
```

You suppose to return `Nothing` in the case the list is empty and `Just 11` if `11` is the last value. I leave it as an excercise.

Comment: Which standard library function is that?

Comment: @MarkSeemann: I think the answer means that `Maybe` is from the standard library, and is often used for non-total functions.

Comment: @MarkSeemann `Maybe` itself is a type-level function :) Willem is right, `Maybe` is the standard way to solve such sort of problems.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ah, yes, thank you. I should learn to read text more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way to define a "default return value" for a Haskell function. But the idea of a "default return value" also is totally unrelated to what you were trying to do, anyway.

In the `Integer` version of your function, you simply did it like this:

```
-- first approach using conditions
myLast :: [Integer] -> Integer
myLast l =
    if null l then
        -1
    else
        l !! ((length l) - 1)
```

You *test* whether the list is empty (using `null l`), and map that case to a valid value of your return type (here you chose `-1`). It's not a "default" return value for when you are "missing" a normal return value; it's just the return value.

The function you're trying to complete has **exactly** the same structure:

```
myLast :: [Either Integer String] -> Either Integer String
myLast l =
    if null l then
        -- what should I return?
    else
        l !! ((length l) - 1)
```

You test whether the list is emtpy using `null l`, if it's not you compute a return value with `last l`, and in the case where it is empty you just need to write down a value of your return type.

This is not any more to do with providing a "default return value" than it was when you wrote `| null l = -1` in the other case. You can't use `-1` here, but that's not because you need a default value, it's just that `-1` is not an element of the type `Either Integer String`. You can pick any element of that type you want and just write it there.

If you were unaware, an `Either` value is only *isomorphic* to "one of two possible types"; you can easily convert the two possible types to the `Either` values and, you can test to see which type is inside and extract the value, but it's not automatic; you do have to actually write the logic to convert, test, and extract. All `Either` values have to use one of the two data constructors of `Either`: they will look like `Left <some-value>` or `Right <some-value>`. In your specific case with `Either Integer String`, it will be `Left <some-number>` or `Right <some-string>`; e.g. `Left 237` or `Right "hello"`. You can't use `237` or `"hello"` *directly* where you need to write a value of type `Either Integer String`.

So you could fill in the blank in your `myLast :: [Either Integer String] -> Either Integer String` function by writing something like this:

```
myLast :: [Either Integer String] -> Either Integer String
myLast l =
    if null l then
        Left (-1)
    else
        l !! ((length l) - 1)
```

(The parentheses around `(-1)` are sadly necessary by default in Haskell so that it doesn't think you're trying to apply the binary `-` operator, as in `Left - 1`; alternatively you could use `Left $ -1`)

Again, you're not "providing a default return value" because there is no such thing. You're simply providing using a test to split into multiple branches, and then providing a perfectly ordinary return value on every branch.

Note that the way `Either` works means you also won't be able to **call** your `myLast` function with a list containing some `Integer` values and some `String` values. i.e. This will never be possible, no matter how you define your function:

```
ghci> myLast [123, "hello", 456, "world"]  -- incorrect!
```

Instead all of the values need to the the *one* type `Either Integer String`, and thus calling it would look like:

```
ghci> myLast [Left 123, Right "hello", Left 456, Right "world"]
```

---

As other answers have mentioned, there are many other improvements you could make to this code, which you'll need to learn eventually. In this answer I've attempted to address just the core confusion, so you can focus on one thing at a time.